# samba share on windows 7 won't give me access to /var but gives me access to everyother directory

Tags: centos, windows-7, samba

i have samba share set up to give me access to my linux box from my windows 7 machine, everything is fine, except i can't access the /var director for some reason through windows. however, i can access every other directory no problem

I the error i get when i try to access the /var directory is:

```
Z:\var is not accessible.

Access is denied.
```

I am using centos 5.5

root is the allowed samba user. and here is my samba configuration:

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   netbios name = SAMBA
   server string = Samba Server %v
   map to guest = Bad User
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 50
   socket options = TCP_NODELAY SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_SNDBUF=8192
   preferred master = No
   local master = No
   dns proxy = No
   security = User

# Share
[root]
   path = /
   valid users = root
   read only = no
   browseable = yes
   writeable = yes
   create mask = 0777
   directory mask = 0777
```

here is my list of my root directory permissions & ownership

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 May 18 16:35 bin
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  1024 May 18 16:36 boot
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root  3960 May 18 20:12 dev
drwxr-xr-x 55 root root  4096 May 19 02:05 etc
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root  4096 May 19 02:05 home
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root  4096 May 18 17:59 lib
drwx------  2 root root 16384 May 18 16:31 lost+found
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jan 26  2010 media
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 May 18 19:40 mnt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jan 26  2010 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 86 root root     0 May 18 20:11 proc
drwxr-x---  2 root root  4096 May 18 20:10 root 
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 May 18 16:36 sbin
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     0 May 18 20:11 selinux
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Jan 26  2010 srv
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root     0 May 18 20:11 sys
drwxrwxrwt  3 root root  4096 May 19 01:28 tmp
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root  4096 May 18 16:34 usr
drwxr-xr-x 18 root root  4096 May 18 17:51 var
```

am i doing something wrong? or is this a centos security thing?

Comment: why you want to share / ? this isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Probably [SELinux](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-selinux.html) is preventing Samba from reading a directory in `/var` as it is not normally required.

- You can turn this off using `setsebool -P samba_export_all_rw=on` but is will decrease Samba security, as Samba would be able to read everywhere.

  A better way would be to move data, which would be accessed by Samba, for example to `/home/samba` and run `setsebool -P samba_enable_home_dirs=on`, as it would allow Samba to read home directories only.

  The best is to configure SELinux allowing Samba to read a directory with particular SELinux label (for example `httpd_sys_content_t` in `/var/www` — check your directory with `ls -lZ`) but this is where it gets a little complicated:

  ```
  yum install selinux-policy-devel
  mkdir /etc/selinux/local
  cd /etc/selinux/local
  (
    echo 'avc: denied { manage_file_perms } for ' \
      ' scontext=system_u:system_r:smb_t ' \
      ' tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t tclass=file'
    echo 'avc: denied { manage_dir_perms } for ' \
      ' scontext=system_u:system_r:smb_t ' \
      ' tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t tclass=dir'
  ) | audit2allow -M local
  semodule -i local.pp
  ```